# Packet wrangling from C to C++ or... how Neither Variant nor Any is a Union

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost

The problem in a nutshell: I'm considering a rewrite of some packet handling code for a UDP protocol ... from C to C++.  Obviously, I can just use the structures that I had with C to model the data,  but then what would be the point?  So, for the sake of argument, we have:

```
struct { uint8:2 type; uint8:6 con_id; uint16 seq_num } packet_header;
struct { packet_header ph; uint16 command; } control_packet;
struct { packet_header ph; uchar8 data[DATASIZE]; } data_packet;
```

In this case, "type" is 0 for data, 1 for control, 2 for encrypted data and 3 for encrypted control.  There would also be structs reprenting each of the control packets, for argument, lets say "open" and "close".

Now... I would normally have a type that the function that fetches the packet returns and the function that sends accepts:

```
struct {
  size_t pkt_len;
  union {
    uchar8 raw_packet[DATASIZE];
    packet_header ph;
    control_packet cp;
    control_open_packet cop;
    control_close_packet ccp;
    data_packet dp; 
  } p; 
} packet;
```

... this is all simplified for argument... but the point is: when sending a packet, we want to create a packet of a certain type and send a generic packet.  Conversely, when receiving a packet, you want to receive a generic packet and and cast it to more specific types as you classify it.

So where's the question?  My question is: if Variant and Any are not appropriate ways to express this, what are?  Am I stuck with union in this case?  Certainly I don't violate the stipulation of POD types (so far) for the union.  I've been scouring both C++11 and Boost (and to some extent looking at C++14 ... although I'm stuck with C++11) and I don't see offered solutions.

Comment: Explain what is Varaint and Any first.

Comment: std::variant or boot::variant.  Similarly std::any or boost::Any  --- I'm sorry... considering at least one meaning of the term is a C++11 feature ... I assumed that people knew what that was.

Comment: There is honestly a mess in current C++ around aliasing rules.  Aliasing involves interpreting a block of memory of type A as type B.  I am uncertain if there is a reasonable and practical way to do what you want to do without doing stupid memcpy tricks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both union as it is in your example or class hierarchy with `packet_header` a the top and specific derived classes for each type of the packet:

```
struct packet_header { uint8:2 type; uint8:6 con_id; uint16 seq_num };
struct control_packet : packet_header { uint16 command; };
struct data_packet: packet_header { uchar8 data[DATASIZE]; };

struct packet
{
  size_t pkt_len;
  union
  {
    uchar8 raw_packet[DATASIZE];
    packet_header ph;
    control_packet cp;
    control_open_packet cop;
    control_close_packet ccp;
    data_packet dp; 
  }; 
};
```

Maybe you need to seek for elegance and flexibility in the code that handles your packets. I doubt that defining data in some other way (using boost or using C++17 features) will lead to a considerable gain.

Note the anonymous union in the `struct packet`. It allows accessing fields of specific packet types directly. C++ style expects the name of the struct directly after the `struct` keyword.